# Android: HttpUrlConnection uses POST to send request bodys (instead of GET)

Tags: android, http, request

I'm developing an Android application which communicates with (our own) API. It was meant to use the API in manipulative requests with the request method **POST** and at not-manipulative requests **GET** (as it should be in *RESTful* applications).

To authenticate or add parameters to the request, the HTTP request body has been used (in both GET and POST requests). (YES, it is possible and allowed to add a request body to GET requests per HTTP definition (see [e.g. this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body))). The post generally says, that it is possible to add a request body, but the server may not use it during the request.

**The problem is**, that the request method is always set to POST, no mather if I set it to GET anywhere during the connection configuration, even if the `getRequestMethod` does return GET after setting it to GET via `setRequestMethod("GET")`.

The android application uses the **HttpsURLConnection** (which is an extended class from *HttpURLConnection*, so it should behave similary).

By calling these methods, a request body will be attended:

```
https.setDoInput(true);
OutputStream os = https.getOutputStream();
os.write(outputInBytes);
os.close();
```

And by calling `https.setRequestMethod("GET")`, the request method should be set to GET.

After a little investigating, the line `OutputStream os = https.getOutputStream();` sets the request method to POST, afterwards I set it to GET again and it remains GET till the end of the connection (as returned by `https.getRequestMethod()`)

But in the end the server receives the request with the request method POST.

So my specific questions are:

- Is there a possible workaround / solution for this problem?
- Is it really that bad to add a request body to a GET request?

Currently I have just set all requests to POST, so there is no problem with it (and I wouldn't have a problem to leave it this way, but for several reasons I would like to know for sure that there is no other way to fix this problem)

Edit: The [documentation of the getOutputStream() method](http://www.innovation.ch/java/HTTPClient/api/HTTPClient/HttpURLConnection.html#getOutputStream%28%29) says:

> The default request method changes to "POST" when this method is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the [`HttpURLConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) is a GET Method (`getDoInput()` is true by default).

If you use [`setDoOutput(true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#setDoOutput%28boolean%29) it will become a POST method.

If you need another method (PUT, DELETE, etc...) then you will use setRequestMethod(string).

And of course you have to select the method you want before the `connect()` method

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am currently setting the request-method to GET _before_ the `connect()` method. The `getRequestMethod` then does return **GET**, but the request is still performed with POST (which is my problem)

Comment: If you are sending data, this will be considered like a post. a GET Method should not send information. The query should be into the url or by adding request properties into the header. Here I see an outputInBytes, what is it ?

Comment: I do get that it is common to send parameters as GET parameters or in the header fields, but [following this post (same link as in original post)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/5045290), it is allowed per RFC to include a request body to a GET request. But I think it will be better to not send a GET request body because not many clients/server do understand that it is possible..

Comment: When I send my request, I use for example `https.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "code=" + code);`

Comment: Ok thanks, that means I will use header fields for authorization and other data that needs to be sent to the server in GET response in further projects. However I will leave this question un-answered for some time, if someone is able to post a workaround for the respone-body-GET problem... :)